# Is there an open source (read free) tool that allows me to see my browser's HTTP commands?

Tags: http, network-protocols, http-protocols

I am getting into HTTP protocol specifics and I would like to see/understand the calls my browser makes as it is being used. I use Firebug (with Firefox) to look at/debug AJAX interactions, etc, but don't see the full HTTP conversation.

**Is there something similar for viewing HTTP commands issued by a browser?**

Comment: Learning about and understanding protocols, especially through real-world inspection, is very much a programming topic. **Voting to re-open**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966), a Firefox add-on, to see HTTP requests and responses, and to manipulate them.

Comment: I installed this. Seems to work out of the box, without too much effort etc

Comment: Works out of the box - no fuss. This is the one for me (at least to get started)

Answer (score 8):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is pretty good for looking at the HTTP level, and [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will let you look at whats going on at the TCP level.

Comment: Fiddler (unless I'm mistaken), only workd for *cough* IE browsers. I tend to use FF predominantly for my webdev, also I found Fiddler a bit 'Fiddly' - i.e. not easy to use die to too much information.

Comment: Fiddler is a proxy, so it works with any browser that supports proxies, including Firefox, Opera, etc. But it is Windows-only.

Comment: @Stick it to THE MAN - actually, you are mistaken. The latest version of Fiddler includes the FiddlerHook add-on for Firefox.

Comment: wireshack looks impressive, but its probably too much (info) for me at this (beginners) stage

Comment: Fiddler 2 has Firefox support and even integrates into the status bar.

Comment: voted up for Etehreal ... errm, WireShark .. sooner or later everyone needs it for something (and it can do it)

Also, check out the various FireFox web designer plugins

Answer (score 6):

[HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) or the venerable [LiveHttpHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829)

Comment: I installed LiveHttpHeaders. Looks like I'll have to RTFM before using it though ...

Comment: LiveHttpHeaders is hard to read when things get complex.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can monitor your connection with Wireshark.

Comment: +1 because Wireshark is actually quite easy to use and you are guaranteed that it won't change, add, or remove any headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the HTTP requests your browser makes for a page (not just AJAX) with the Firebug net panel. Or you can switch to a proxy tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see all the http requests made by the browser. If you need more detail, [Microsoft VRTA](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=119f3477-dced-41e3-a0e7-d8b5cae893a3&displaylang=en) is a free tool that makes netmon data easier to read, and doesn't depend on a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy from [Burp Suite](http://www.portswigger.net/suite/) lets you see/modify HTTP requests/responses.